# How to use Wordpress' http.php in external projects?

Tags: php, text-parsing, file-access

Answer : Implemented using Curl...

```
$file = "http://abc.com/data//output.txt";
$ch = curl_init($file);
$fp = @fopen("out.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
$file = "out.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
```

I am trying to parse data from a pipe-delimited text file hosted on another server which in turn will be inserted in a database. My host (1and1) disabled **allow_url_fopen** in **php.ini** I guess.

Error message :

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in
```

Code :

```
    <?


// make sure curl is installed
if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
   // initialize a new curl resource
   $ch = curl_init(); 

   // set the url to fetch
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://abc.com/data/output.txt'); 

   // don't give me the headers just the content
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

   // return the value instead of printing the response to browser
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

   // use a user agent to mimic a browser
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0'); 

   $content = curl_exec($ch); 

   // remember to always close the session and free all resources 
   curl_close($ch); 
} else {
   // curl library is not installed so we better use something else
}

//$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));

//fclose ($fd); 
$delimiter = "|";
$splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);
$counter = "";
?>
<font color="blue" face="arial" size="4">Complete File Contents</font>
<hr>
<?
echo $contents;
?>

<br><br>
<font color="blue" face="arial" size="4">Split File Contents</font>
<hr>
<?
foreach ( $splitcontents as $color )
{

$counter = $counter+1;
echo "<b>Split $counter: </b> $colorn<br>";
}

?>
```

Wordpress has this cool http.php file. Is there a better way of doing it? If not, how do I use http.php for this task? Thank you guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `file_get_contents()`, or the CURL library.

This article has some examples: [Reading a Remote File Using PHP](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much. Replaced with curl but no contents are being displayed. Could you please debug this new code? Thanks again...

Comment: Implemented using Curl. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't get any results... Did you try getting a page like google?  Are you sure there are no errors occurring?  You might want to check your error log to make sure that CURL is working correctly.